# Double quotes in Linux script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a script that moves to a specific folder, then renames and moves all files to another location.
However, I'm getting an error at the end of the JHEAD command because of the space between the date and time formatting.
I've tried using double quotes, quotes around the space, etc. Nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
cd /home/fitur/Backup/Temp/

jhead_cmd='jhead -norot -ft -n/home/fitur/Pictures/Photos/%Y/%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S {}'

find . -type f -name "*.JP*" -exec $jhead_cmd \;
find . -type f -name "*.jp*" -exec $jhead_cmd \;
```

Comment: Is it anything to do with no space between `-n` and `/home...` in your jhead_cmd variable? The -n obviously means to pass a location string... double quotes should be used as you are doing formating within, I would have thought single quotes would be a literal string...?

Comment: @BigChris: Manpage says that's OK: http://linux.die.net/man/1/jhead

Comment: Just to comment on my own post. It's supposed to be -nf/home/fitur/Pictures/Photos/%Y/%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S {}' 
and not -n/home/fitur/Pictures/Photos/%Y/%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S {}'

Notice the underline between %Y.%m-%d and %H:%M:%S. Its supposed to be a spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine the two `find` commands by making the name case insensitive you can avoid the variable:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jp*" -exec jhead [...] {} \;
```